# Undo a merge after time, what happens?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

How do i undo a merge that has been pushed and later been branched off? And what happens to the repo?

This has been asked in different variations before but im not sure if any of the answers explains what happens after.

Assume this is the state of the repo:

```
A--B--C---------G--H
       \       /    \
        D--E--F      I--J
```

After reading several answers i assume the i should do a git revert?? on G? Or git reset?

What happens to the H,I,J code, that may use some of the code that was merged, if i do a git reset or git revert on the FG merge?

Im still a noob on using the more advanced features of git :/

**Edit1:** I should mention that this isn't a public repo. All the branches are maintained by a small inhouse team.

Comment: What would you want the code to look like after this undo? Should It be exactly like G?

Comment: So you want to have a checkout of C to restart working on?

Comment: What i want is to undo the merge and continue working on the DEF branch, that branch wasn't ready to be merged. But i dont want to mess up the IJ branch. The DEF branch will be merged again at a later stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What i want is to undo the merge and continue working on the DEF branch

[Undoing a merge through a revert](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/02/undoing-merges.html) is one way which at least does not change the history of the main branch

```
git revert -m 1 G
```

And you can go on on branch `DEF`n which is unaware of the merge: you can add new commits and merge later. 
However, as [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889610/undo-a-merge-after-time-what-happens/39889912#comment67071835_39889912) by [lucash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1406321/lucash), that **will not reapply the changes from commits `D`, `E` and `F`** but only merge the new commits from that branch, most probably leading to problems due to the missing changes which were aware in the `DEF` branch.
So you will need first to revert the revert-commit (result of `git revert -m 1 G`) before merging the branch to avoid that problem.

`IJK` can remain on `H`: the revert would have cancelled changes introduced by `G`, and would not have affected `H`.

Comment: I think in this case merging the branch DEF again later on will not reapply the changes from commits D, E and F but only merge the new commits from that branch, most probably leading to problems due to the missing changes which were aware in the DEF branch. You could revert the revert-commit (result of `git revert -m 1 G`) before merging the branch to avoid that problem.

Comment: @lucash Good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Another, and I believe simpler way to accomplish what you want would be to make a new branch from commit "F". Continue making your changes to your D E F series. Then merge back to your "main" branch (starting A B C). At that point whoever is working I J won't have your changes, and you won't affect them. But they can merge I J into A B C anytime they want without affecting you either.

Reverts can be messy. Especially reverting merges. And the previous answer is correct, you would have to either revert the revert, or cherry pick the reverted merge AFTER you finish making your changes. If your changes touch the files that were reverted, you will likely have a messy merge on your hands. :(

If someone else want to make a branch and work without your DEF changes, just have them branch from C, make their changes and merge in after they are done. It won't matter if they merge before or after you are done.

The place that my suggestion would break down is if I J are done, and ready to be pushed to production, and D E F are not yet done. Then a revert does become an unfortunate necessity. :(

Good luck!